Can I fix my camera? (Kodak EasyShare C180)
I recently was given one of my dad's old cameras (Kodak EasyShare C180) and the buttons don't work. The camera will turn on and take pictures but none of the buttons except for the shutter button work and the pictures aren't saved. Is there any way I can fix this?

This is 15 years old P&S camera. Maybe will be wise to keep it as it is and make photos with phone?

I think you need to have a word with your dad

Try new batteries.   The old ones may not be holding enough charge to power all functions.

This is supported by the "Troubleshooting" section of the user manual (found online in various locations) which says for "Camera buttons and controls do not function" that you should "Make sure the batteries are charged and installed correctly"
